# HTML5/CSS width and border

Tags: html, css

I am creating an html5 file that is meant to be printed. One part of the printed output is a form to be manually filled out on the printed output. I want to create underlines under the blanks as is normal on such a form.

The example code at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dim_height allows me to define a width of a

element, and apply a border-bottom css property to it. The output is a faux underline the width of the element, even if there is no text in the

element.

The same code in both Safari and Chrome on OS X Yosemite does not show any bottom border.

Is there a way to generate an underline of a specified length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. make a custom tag element called 'sp' eg. `<p>THIS IS A <sp/> SPACE</p>`
2. CSS for the new 'sp' tag:

> ```
> sp:before {
>     content: '\2003\2003\2003\2003\2003'; // '\2003' is the ISO code used in CSS for a 4 unit wide whitespace. Here I use 5 of them.
>     text-decoration:underline;
>     }
> ```

3. Add  according to the width you need (example below):

```css
sp:before { 
content: '\2003\2003\2003\2003\2003'; 
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<p>THIS IS A <sp/> SPACE</p>
<p>THIS IS A <sp/><sp/> SPACE</p>
<p>THIS IS A <sp/><sp/><sp/> SPACE</p>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Worked great, although Komodo Edit threw an error on the custom tag.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work for you?

```css
.underline {
  width: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
bla <span class="underline"></span> bla
```

However, instead of giving the underline a fixed width, I would suggest you adapt the width of the underlined area dynamically according to the container's width.

Answer (score 0):

Set a width, ideally a percentage so it can adapt if the page size or layout changes. 100% if your container is doing layout, some other percent as appropriate. You can use inches (`in`), centimeters (`cm`), and so on, but you will need to test it. Just do not use pixels (`px`). Also, use `pt` for the border line as that is something a printer generally renders consistently.

```
@media print {
  input[type=text] {
    border-bottom: 1pt solid #000;
    width: 50%; /* use a % value, or maybe in, but not px */
  }
}
```

This only fires when the page is printed. It removes the border from any `<input type="text">`.

Since I misunderstood your question at first, I initially wrote CSS to underline only text that was already entered and to keep the width of the text. So I'll put that here anyway.

```
@media print {
  input[type=text] {
    border: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}
```

It underlines the text in the field, which takes its length from the width of the text anyway.

In both cases, no custom elements, no special classes, no script.

- EDIT: I should have qualified, I come from a world where forms that are printed are usually backed by an on-screen form, so I started there.